# Make database objects non-searchable

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

Using the django-haystack and solr as a search engine, I have successfully implemented a search engine which throws out the list of users whose usernames, first names, last names, or email addresses match the given query.

**search_indexes.py**

```
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    first_name = CharField(model_attr='first_name')
    last_name = CharField(model_attr='last_name')
    email = CharField(model_attr='email')

    def index_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.exclude(username='root')

site.register(User, UserIndex)
```

and

**user_text.txt**

```
{{ object.username }}
{{ object.first_name }}
{{ object.last_name }}
{{ object.email }}
```

However, I am planning to let the users set their privacy settings so that they will not be searchable with their first_name, last_name, or email address.

I have been banging my head and my computer for days trying to accomplish this functionality but haven't found any real good solution yet.

Is it at all possible to accomplish the above functionality?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It depends on your architecture: if they have direct access to Solr, or if they access it through a service tier that you have built in your server.

Comment: Like what Eduardo said. But if this is not a computer-product, but a web service, end-users don't have access to the db. You can probably just do `exclude(username='root' or searchable=False)` where `searchable` is a new field (db attribute) in your class. I think that should work... and by default, depending on the purpose of this search query, you can either make it searchable or not. Other than that, I don't really understand your question if I am wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a constraints table and e.g. use haystack's SearchQuerySet to exclude upon. Here's an example using tastypie as an API, but this might as well be your custom service or view layer.

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#advanced-filtering

Comment: Hello Hedde, thank you directing me to exactly what I needed! You are awesome.